# web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted

Tags: solidity, web3.py

Contract #1 is a functioning contract (runs with no issues)

Contract #2 is a modified version of Contract #1 with the following changes:

- Modified `exchangeRouterAddress` from being hardcoded to being passed as an arg to the main function `buy()`.
- Brokedown `buy()` function into smaller functions due to "Stack Too Deep" compiling errors.
- Hardcoded the value input from Contract #1

Now I've successfully compiled and deployed Contract #2 but running into error `web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted`. Please help me spot the cause of this error so that Contract #2 can perform just as Contract #1 without issues. Thanks

Contract #1:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

interface IERC20 {
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

interface IUniswapV2Router01 {
    function factory() external pure returns (address);
    function WETH() external pure returns (address);
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}

interface IUniswapV2Router02 is IUniswapV2Router01 {
    function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external payable;
    function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external;
}

interface IWETH {
    function deposit() external payable;
}

contract ReBuy {
    receive() external payable {}
    
    address exchangeRouterAddress = 0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E;
    
    function buy(address baseToken, address token) public payable returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256[] memory gas = new uint256[](2);

        IUniswapV2Router02 exchangeRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(exchangeRouterAddress);

        IERC20 _token = IERC20(token);
        IERC20 _baseToken = IERC20(baseToken);
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);

        if(baseToken != exchangeRouter.WETH()) {
            path[0] = exchangeRouter.WETH();
            path[1] = baseToken;
            exchangeRouter.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens{value: msg.value}(0, path, address(this), block.timestamp + 20);
        }
        else {
            IWETH(baseToken).deposit{value: msg.value}();
        }

        uint256 amount = _baseToken.balanceOf(address(this));
        
        path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = baseToken;
        path[1] = token;

        uint256 expectedToken = exchangeRouter.getAmountsOut(amount, path)[1];
        _baseToken.approve(exchangeRouterAddress, type(uint256).max);
        uint256 startGas = gasleft();
        exchangeRouter.swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(amount, 0, path, address(this), block.timestamp + 20);
        gas[0] = startGas - gasleft();
        uint256 receivedToken = _token.balanceOf(address(this));

        path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = token;
        path[1] = baseToken;


        uint256 expectedBaseToken = exchangeRouter.getAmountsOut(receivedToken, path)[1];
        _token.approve(exchangeRouterAddress, type(uint256).max);
        startGas = gasleft();
        exchangeRouter.swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(receivedToken, 0, path, address(this), block.timestamp + 20);
        gas[1] = startGas - gasleft();
        
        uint256 receivedBaseToken = _baseToken.balanceOf(address(this));

        return (expectedToken, receivedToken, gas[0], expectedBaseToken, receivedBaseToken, gas[1]);
    }
}
```

Contract #2:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

interface IERC20 {
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

interface IUniswapV2Router01 {
    function factory() external pure returns (address);
    function WETH() external pure returns (address);
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}

interface IUniswapV2Router02 is IUniswapV2Router01 {
    function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external payable;
    function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external;
}

interface IWETH {
    function deposit() external payable;
}

contract ReBuy {
    struct ExchangeResult {
        uint256 expected;
        uint256 received;
        uint256 gas;
    }

    function deposit(address token, address exchangeRouterAddress) internal {
        IUniswapV2Router02 exchangeRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(exchangeRouterAddress);
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);

        if (token != exchangeRouter.WETH()) {
            path[0] = exchangeRouter.WETH();
            path[1] = token;
            exchangeRouter.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens{value: 1000000000000000000}(0, path, address(this), block.timestamp + 20);
        } 
        else {
            IWETH(token).deposit{value: 1000000000000000000}();
        }
    }

    function exchangeToken(address fromToken, address toToken, address exchangeRouterAddress, uint256 amount) private returns (uint256, uint256, uint256)
    {
        IUniswapV2Router02 exchangeRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(exchangeRouterAddress);

        uint256 expected;
        uint256 received;
        uint256 gas;

        //uint256[] memory gas = new uint256[](2);
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);

        IERC20 token = IERC20(fromToken);
        path[0] = fromToken;
        path[1] = toToken;

        expected = exchangeRouter.getAmountsOut(amount, path)[1];
        token.approve(exchangeRouterAddress, type(uint256).max);
        gas = gasleft();

        exchangeRouter.swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(amount, 0, path, address(this), block.timestamp + 20);
        gas = gas - gasleft();
        token = IERC20(toToken);
        received = token.balanceOf(address(this));

        return (expected, received, gas);
    }

    function buy(address baseToken, address token, address exchangeRouterAddress) public payable returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256)
    {
        IERC20 _baseToken = IERC20(baseToken);
        uint256 amount;
        ExchangeResult memory tokenRes;
        ExchangeResult memory baseTokenRes;

        deposit(baseToken, exchangeRouterAddress);
        amount = _baseToken.balanceOf(address(this));

        (tokenRes.expected, tokenRes.received, tokenRes.gas) = exchangeToken(baseToken, token, exchangeRouterAddress, amount);

        (baseTokenRes.expected, baseTokenRes.received, baseTokenRes.gas) = exchangeToken(token, baseToken, exchangeRouterAddress, tokenRes.received);

        // Finally return all results    
        return (tokenRes.expected, tokenRes.received, tokenRes.gas, baseTokenRes.expected, baseTokenRes.received, baseTokenRes.gas);
    }
}
```

Sample of how I call the `buy()` function (Contract #2 entry function) in python:

```
token = '0x67382a3364b97e09f727afb388fe817de18f7a18'  # Random token just for test
base_token = '0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c'    # WBNB
router_address = '0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E'    # Pancake Router

deployed_contract = # Place Contract #2 address after deployment here
deployed_contract_ABI = '[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"baseToken","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"exchangeRouterAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"simulate_txn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]'

deployed_contract = web3.toChecksumAddress(deployed_contract )
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=deployed_contract , abi=deployed_contract_ABI )
results = contract.functions.buy(base_token , token, router_address ).call()  

print(results)  # Returns 6 values
```